# Apache Phoenix: about the secondary index upsert performance on write-heavy table

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I’d like get a rough idea about the upsert performance on write heavy table which has a secondary index.

The index has all the fields of the table(in fact, the number of the non-row-key fields is one, which is varbinary type).

I ran a rough test, and the result is as follows:

- table with a secondary index: 4.3 min
- table without a secondary index: 53 sec

The test is done with an Apache Spark program with the PhoenixInputFormat.

The secondary index is global mutable.

The result is, for me, somewhat too slow compared to a table without a secondary index.

It is about 4.7 times slower. I wish that it would be around 2 ~ 2.5 times. (Since it actually writes to 2 tables)

Is this a typical performance penalty?

If so, I think I must give up a (global, mutable) secondary index for the write-heavy tables.

*UPDATE*

My test cluster is consist of 1 name node and 3 data nodes. (It's tiny)

Data node machine spec is as follows: (by no means powerful)

- CPU: Core i7-4790 (# of cores: 4, # of threads: 8)
- RAM: 32GB (8GB x 4)
- HDD: 8TB (2TB x 4)
- Network: 1Gb

Software specs:

- Hadoop: Hortonworks HDP 2.2 (Hadoop 2.6)
- Apache Spark: 1.3.0
- Apache Phoenix: 4.3.1

The number of records upserted is about 6 million. it has only one column (the datatype is varbinary) and it's small. (well below 1k)

Comment: I think something went wrong. Have you considered http://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html *Tuning* section? How have you measured performance? Which hardware do you use?

Comment: @SashaEgorov I've updated the question with the hardware and software spec. BTW, actually a region server went down short time after the test.

Comment: BTW I cannot subscribe to the phoenix mailing list... I don't know what's wrong.